# Variable assignment and the comma operator

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Can anybody explain for me:

```
int a, b, c, d;
a = 2;
b = 4;
c = a, b;
d = (a, b);
```

Why `c == 2` and `d == 4` ???

Comment: Don't post code and results in images, it's a PITA to see on mobile devices, and to try your code in a compiler as well. -1 until you fix it.

Comment: OK, So sorry about that.

Comment: Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two statements are both evaluated as

```
c = a;
d = b;
```

due to how the *comma* operator (which has the lowest precedence of any operator) works in C and C++.

For the first one, `c = a` is evaluated first (as `=` has higher precedence than the comma operator) then `b` (which is a no-op) is evaluated. The *entire expression* has a value `b` but that's not assigned to anything.

For `d = (a, b);`, `(a, b)` is first evaluated due to the parentheses. This has a value `b`, and that is assigned to `d`.

Comment: @TrầnHồngPhát - You should accept this answer, since it helped you and it's spot on.